# AWS Code Deploy disable block traffic and allow traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy

Does anyone know if there is a way to disable the BlockTraffic and AllowTraffic steps in AWS CodeDeploy? These steps are not in my appspec but they run anyway and take a very long time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It can be set from the Edit Deployment Group page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**BlockTraffic**:  During this deployment lifecycle event, internet traffic is blocked from accessing instances that are currently serving traffic. This event is reserved for the CodeDeploy agent and cannot be used to run scripts.

**AllowTraffic**: During this deployment lifecycle event, internet traffic is allowed to access instances after a deployment. This event is reserved for the CodeDeploy agent and cannot be used to run scripts.  **

As exaplaiend in this [thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=254752) the event hooks can't be disabled. The reason for their long  execution time is that they CodeDeploy uses health check of your balancer. Thus you need to adjust the health checks setting if you want these processes to be faster.

Comment: I have 6 applications, each behind its own ALB having their own target groups. Only 2 of them go through the BlockTraffic, AllowTraffic workflow.  The other 4 just run the steps I define in the appsec.  For the 2 that go through this whole workflow, I can see in the deploy history that they have skipped it before.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: For me the issue was Deregistration delay
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#deregistration-delay